# ImageDraw from PIL library not working for some sinhala characters

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am generating some text contained images using ImageDraw. I am using sinhala unicode font; Nirmala.ttf for that. It works fine for most of the characters. But for some characters, it does not draw correctly.  Here is the python code.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import random
import string
import codecs
import os
f = codecs.open("batches.meta.txt", encoding="utf-8")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
print(lines)
for i in range(0,len(lines)):       
    line= lines[i]
    if(not os.path.exists('training-images/'+str(i))):
        os.mkdir('training-images/'+str(i)) 
    textlength = len(line)  
    img = Image.new('RGB', (28*textlength+20, 70), color = (255, 255, 255))  
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('/fonttype/Nirmala.ttf', 30)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    d.text((10,10), line, font=fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))  
    img.save('training-images/'+str(i)+'/'+line+'.png') 
f.close()
```

Here is the image of that. [Example text image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STFHu.png)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `codecs`? And I presume we need `batches.meta.txt` to try your code?

Comment: ග
ගා
ගැ
ගෙ
ගේ
ගො
ගෝ This is what is in the batches.meta.txt